# Dynamic memory on a function new char[size] vs char[size]

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have this function that has a string with a pre-defined buffer (the buffer is defined when calling a function).

My question is, why doesn't the compiler throws me an error whenever I do the following (without the new operator?):

```
int crc32test(unsigned char *write_string, int buffer_size){
     // Append CRC32 to string
     int CRC_NBYTES = 4;
     int new_buffer_size = buffer_size + CRC_NBYTES; // Current buffer size + CRC

     // HERE (DECLARATION OF THE STRING)
     unsigned char appendedcrc_string[new_buffer_size];

     return 0;

}
```

isn't THIS the correct way to do it..?

```
int crc32test(unsigned char *write_string, int buffer_size){
      // Append CRC32 to string
     int CRC_NBYTES = 4;
     int new_buffer_size = buffer_size + CRC_NBYTES; // Current buffer size + CRC

     // HERE (DECLARATION OF THE STRING USING NEW)
     unsigned char * appendedcrc_string = new unsigned char[new_buffer_size+1];


     delete[] appendedcrc_string ;

     return 0;

}
```

And I actually compiled both, and both worked. Why isn't the compiler throwing me any error? 
And is there a reason to use the new operator if apparently the former function works too?

Comment: The  first (using `unsigned char appendedcrc_string[new_buffer_size]`) is not valid C++.  However, some compilers support it as a *non-standard* extension.

Comment: You are allocating on stack..New operator allocate on heap

Comment: @setia_   that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Note that this code has a potential security vulnerability, if `buffer_size` is within 4 of `INT_MAX` then there is integer overflow causing undefined behaviour

Comment: Your first block creates a C *Variable Length Array* (VLA) which is not part of the C++ standard. Compilers like gnu g++ support it as an extension but it is not portable.

Comment: Got it. It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few answers here already, and I'm going to repeat several things said already. The first form you use is not valid C++, but will work in certain versions of GCC and CLang... It is decidedly non-portable.

There are a few options that you have as alternatives:

- Use `std::string<unsigned char>` for your input and `s.append(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(crc), 4);`
- Similarly, you can use `std::vector<unsigned char>`
- If your need is just for a simple resizable buffer, you can use `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` and use `memcpy` & `std::swap`, etc to move the data into a resized buffer and then free the old buffer.
- As a non-portable alternative for temporary buffer creation, the `alloca()` function carves out a buffer by twiddling the stack pointer. It doesn't play very well with C++ features but it can be used if extremely careful about ensuring that the function will never have an exception thrown from it.
- Store the CRC with the buffer in a structure like

  ```
  struct input {
      std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> buffer;
      uint32_t crc;
  }
  ```

  And deal with the concatenation of the CRC and buffer someplace else in your code (i.e. on output). This, I believe is the best method.

Answer (score 2):

The first code is ill-formed, however some compilers default to a mode where non-standard extensions are accepted.

You should be able to specify compiler switches for standard conformance. For example, in gcc, `-std=c++17 -pedantic`.

The second code is "correct" although not the preferred way either, you should use a container which frees the memory when execution leaves the scope, instead of a manual delete.  For example, `std::vector<unsigned char> buf(new_buffer_size + 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example uses a C99 feature called Variable Length Arrays (VLA), that e.g. g++ by default supports as a C++ language extension. It's non-standard code.

Instead of the second example and similar, you should preferably use `std::vector`.